# How to solve PageSpeed Insights test site performance question mark

Tags: pagespeed-insights

When using PageSpeed Insights to test website performance, SEO metrics scores are not displayed and are displayed as question marks

Detection site robots.txt file no problem

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [tour], [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [ask]